How to use acf fields in custom template
I created a custom template with the title of downloads and I want to display the value of an acf field that is on the WooCommerce product editing page, but unfortunately it is not displayed.
  <p><?php echo the_field('version-pro'); ?></p>

Don't use echo with the_field() https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/
